# how to show multiple groups in add-ins?

Tags: office-js

My add-ins contains multiple controls,I want to arrage controls in multiple Groups rather an in only one group.

I created multiple Groups,but doesn't work.

How can I do it?

[Api Reference](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/customtab)

```
          <Group id="Contoso.Tab1.Group1">
            <!--Label for your group. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
            <Label resid="Contoso.Tab1.GroupLabel" />
            <Icon>
              <!-- Sample Todo: Each size needs its own icon resource or it will look distorted when resized -->
              <!--Icons. Required sizes 16,31,80, optional 20, 24, 40, 48, 64. Strongly recommended to provide all sizes for great UX -->
              <!--Use PNG icons and remember that all URLs on the resources section must use HTTPS -->
              <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
              <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
              <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
            </Icon>

            <!--Control. It can be of type "Button" or "Menu" -->
            <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.FunctionButton">
              <!--Label for your button. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
              <Label resid="Contoso.FunctionButton.Label" />
              <Supertip>
                <!--ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                <Title resid="Contoso.FunctionButton.Label" />
                <!--ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource -->
                <Description resid="Contoso.FunctionButton.Tooltip" />
              </Supertip>
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.FunctionButton.Icon" />
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.FunctionButton.Icon" />
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.FunctionButton.Icon" />
              </Icon>
              <!--This is what happens when the command is triggered (E.g. click on the Ribbon). Supported actions are ExecuteFuncion or ShowTaskpane-->
              <!--Look at the FunctionFile.html page for reference on how to implement the function -->
              <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                <!--Name of the function to call. This function needs to exist in the global DOM namespace of the function file-->
                <FunctionName>writeText</FunctionName>
              </Action>
            </Control> 

          <!-- ....... -->
          </Group>
```

Comment: You need to provide more on what exactly doesn't work, other than saying it doesn't work. Provide entire manifest file, other than (...). There is some error inside those dots. The common mistake is usually during copy&past ppl forget to change id's of the elements. They must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's only possible to create multiple groups if you use your own new add-in tab. You cannot create multiple groups on an existing tab.